# Send only the key of the check_box_tag if checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a bunch of filter categories represented by checkboxes, right now it's sending the full name + `on` in the `query_params`.

```
/?max%5D=5&Movies=on&Art=on&Outdoors=on
```

Instead, I'd rather just look for the presence of the key to know it's there.  This would make the url a bit shorter for people to copy/paste.

```
/?max%5D=5&Movies&Art&Outdoors
```

Or, can I have one `category` key with all the checkboxes as values?

Answer (score -1):

I think it's not possible by default, you'd have to construct an onsubmit script to build the URL and redirect to it, rather than posting directly to the server. You might be better off leaving it as it is.

Comment: So basically not possible without some JS?

Comment: Don’t think so mate

Comment: Do you submit any form after checkbox are checked ? OR as soon as you select checkbox it automatically submited?

Comment: Nope, you’d build an URL from the form parameters basically, key value pairs, and skip the value for checkboxes, then window.location.href to redirect. This would not guarantee the server will accept your request though.